# Django-tables2 - how to set default value for all columns?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

**Django-tables2** renders double dash in case there is no value in the cell. We can change it explicitely specifying `default` attribute for every column.

Can I do that for all columns at once?

Of course I tried to override `__init__` method but `Table.columns` can't be modified and `Table.base_columns` seems to cause the same problem.

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    for name,col in self.base_columns.items():
        col.default = ''

    super(DopytyTable,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

**raises**

> ```
> col.default = '' 
> AttributeError: can't set attribute
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to modify columns inside `__init__` method but there is even more simple way to do that. Unfortunately it isn't documented but it works correctly for me.

Just add `default` attribute to `class Meta`:

```
class Table(Table):
    class Meta:
        default = ''
```

Comment: You are very welcome to [open a pull request](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/pull/new/master) to add such changes to the docs!

Comment: Actually, it is documented: [as argument to `Table`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.tables.Table). The option of using a  `Table.Meta` attribute isn't, so that's a good candidate to be documented.